# Best compression for operating system image

Tags: linux, debian, tar, compression, gzip

I have an Operating system image of size 2.5G.

I have a device with a limited size. Thus I was looking for the best possible solution for providing the compression.

Below are the commands and results of their compression:

1.tar with gzip:

```
tar c Os.img | gzip --best > Os.tar.gz
```

This command returned an image of 1.3G.

2.Xz only:

```
xz -z -v -k Os.img
```

This command returned an image of 1021M.

3.Xz with -9:

```
xz -z -v -9 -k Os.img
```

This command returned an image of 950M.

4.tar with Xz and -9:

```
tar cv Os.img | xz -9 -k > Os.tar.xz
```

This command returned an image of 950M.

5.tar with Xz -9 and -e:

```
xz -z -v -9 -k -e Os.img
```

This command returned an image of 949M.

6.lrzip:

```
lrzip -z -v Os.img
```

This command returned an image of 729M.

Is there any other possible best solution or command line tool ( preferable ) for the compression?

Comment: Using `tar` will not make much difference as it's a single file. The `tar` utility will not compress the file differently from what you would do if you first created the tar archive and then compressed it, in two steps.

Comment: What portability do you need? The methods with highest compression need more RAM also for extraction (decompression).

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1040196/what-is-the-best-unix-compression-utility) (which is still valid... no groundbreaking algorithms have appeared since).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try out zstandard:

Highest "standard" compression option:
`zstd -19 -c Os.img >Os.img.zstd`

Highest ultra compression option:
`zstd -22 --ultra -c Os.img >Os.img.zstd`

Your mileage may vary, but if compression time is not important, but size matters, than zstd is your friend.

Comment: adding `--long=31` to that list might improve things even more, if there is some long distance deduplication available within the image.